# Share Single Datatable in Multi Threading in C#

Tags: multithreading, locking, shared-memory

I have an application, which have three threads. which access single datatable.
Each thread print one row at single time. It should not repeat.but In my application  all three threads are print all row from datatable.

I want that one row should print only once.

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ThreadStart testThread1Start = new ThreadStart(new program().testThread1);
            ThreadStart testThread2Start = new ThreadStart(new Program().testThread2);

            Thread[] testThread = new Thread[2];
            testThread[0] = new Thread(testThread1Start);
            testThread[1] = new Thread(testThread2Start);

            foreach (Thread myThread in testThread)
            {
                myThread.Start();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private void testThread2()
        {          
            DataTable dt = SQLite.ExecuteQuery("SELECT id,name,address FROM example ");
            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {            
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    lock (dt.Rows[i])
                    {
                        var Id = dt.Rows[i]["Id"].ToString();
                        SQLite.ExecuteNonQuery("update example set DisplayDataStatus = 1 where id= '" + Id + "' ");
                        var name = dt.Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
                        var address = dt.Rows[i]["address"].ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine("ID:"+Id+"|Name:"+name+"|address:"+adress);
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            else
            {}
        }

        private void testThread1()
        {
            DataTable dt = SQLite.ExecuteQuery("SELECT id,name,address FROM example ");
            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {            
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    lock (dt.Rows[i])
                    {
                        var Id = dt.Rows[i]["Id"].ToString();
                        SQLite.ExecuteNonQuery("update example set DisplayDataStatus = 1 where id= '" + Id + "' ");
                        var name = dt.Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
                        var address = dt.Rows[i]["address"].ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine("ID:"+Id+"|Name:"+name+"|address:"+adress);
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            else
            {}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIRST**

Why are you re-executing the "`SQLite.ExecuteQuery`" in every single thread? If you only want to print all the rows in the table without blocking UI, it's enough to have a **single** background `Thread` that executes the query and then prints the rows.
Having more threads that try to read from the *same* database and try to write to the *same* `Console`, can slow down your application instead of speeding it up (because the time of execution is the same but you have to sum the time required for all the context-switches between threads).

**SECOND**

Ok, suppose you still need 3 threads to execute other parallel operations.

Suppose the `DataTable` instance is the same for all threads.
The lock on the `Row` is only blocking the threads from writing that `Row` **at the same time**. Suppose `Thread` T1 is writing `Row` R1. T2 is blocked on R1 and cannot write it. Then T1 finishes, unblocks R1 and blocks R2. Because R1 is now unblocked, T2 enters the `lock` section of R1 and write R1. And so on. So all the threads write all the rows, but at different moments.

Suppose instead that every `Thread` creates its own `DataTable`, as your code does. If T1 locks on `dt.Row[0]`, that's not the same object as `dt.Row[0]` of T2! They're separate objects, so a lock section won't block the execution of any other thread!

**THIRD**

The "`if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)`" statement is completely useless.
When you enter the `for` loop, and there are no rows, the loop exits at the first check without consequences.

A check that makes sense before a for/foreach loop is the one against null list. So you can write:

"`if (Rows != null) { for (int i = 0; i < Rows.Count; i++) { ... ... ... }`"

**UPDATE**

If you only have to print the rows to the Console, you can have 1000 threads, but since they all print to the same single Console, you have 999 useless threads. The situation is different if you have to perform some "expensive" operation on a row and *then* display it to the Console. In this case, try this:

- Execute a query that retrieves only the Rows count.
- Divide all the rows in three ranges based on the total count, assign one range to each thread and start each thread. For example, T1 execute the query only for the rows 0-14999, T2 executes for 15000-29999, and so on.
- The method passed to each thread can be the same, but with different input `startRow` and `endRow` numbers. The method creates a DataTable only with those rows and print only those rows to the Console.

This solution doesn't print the rows all in order, anyway. Is that a requirement?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I leave this topic. But after getting your response I will reopen it and try it. Actually I want that one row should print only once. And for fast execution Purpose I have used multi threading. Because approx more then 50000 rows available in data-table. How should I implement code so that all rows are print only once with fast execution?? @MK87